# Switch version of mono in macOS?

Tags: macos, mono, unreal-engine4

I have 3 versions of mono framework: 5.2, 6.4 and 6.8.

For unreal engine 4.22 I need v5.
For 4.23+, I need v6.

How can I quickly switch between them? Bash script maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it's a little bit late, but I think it might be helpful for someone.

There is a directory
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/

It contains existing mono versions and also the directory "Current" which is a symlink to one of versions that are stored in this directory.

So, to switch mono version, for example,  from 5.12 to 6.12 you should remove Current

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/
sudo rm -rf Current
```

, and create a new symlink

```
sudo ln -s 6.12.0/ Current
```

You can try to check the version after that

```
mono -V
```